# Lorentz invariance

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

In QED loop renormalization, Lorentz invariance is often used to express the possible momentum-dependence of the propagators.

For example, the propagator corresponding to the fermion loop is

$$ie_0^2 \Pi^{\mu \nu}(k) = \frac{-e_0^2}{(2\pi)^4} 
\int d^4p \frac{\text{Tr}
[\gamma^\mu(p\!\!/+k\!\!/+m_0) \gamma^\nu (p\!\!/+m_0)]}
{[(p+k)^2-m_0^2+i\epsilon][p^2-m_0^2+i\epsilon]}.$$

Under Lorentz invariance, we have $\Pi^{\mu \nu}(k) = -A(k^2) g ^{\mu \nu}+ B(k^2)k^\mu k^\nu$.

Similarly, the propagator corresponding to the electron self-energy is $\Sigma (p)$ and under Lorentz invariance, it can be written as $\Sigma(p) = A + B(\gamma^\mu p_\mu-m)+\Sigma_c(p)(\gamma^\mu p_\mu-m)$ with $A$, $B$ constants and $\Sigma_c(p)$ vanishing linearly when $\gamma^\mu p_\mu$ tends to $m$.

Finally, the corrected vertex is of the form $\Lambda^\mu(p^\prime,p)$. Under Lorentz invariance, $\bar{u}(p)\Lambda^\mu(p,p)u(p) = A \bar{u}(p)\gamma^\mu u(p) + B p^\mu \bar{u}(p) u(p)$ with $A$ and $B$ constants.

In these three cases, how does the Lorentz invariance restrict the possible dependence of the expressions? Why can't there be other terms?

Comment: *Why can't there be higher orders terms?* What would be an example of a higher-order term of $\Pi^{\mu\nu}$? Please be explicit.

Comment: I was thinking of term like $k^\mu \gamma^\nu$, $k^\mu \sigma^{\nu \alpha} k_\alpha$, ... I was also thinking of terms in $(p_\mu \sigma^\mu)^3$ or $(p_\mu \sigma^\mu)^4$ in $\Sigma(p)$.

Comment: $\Pi^{\mu\nu}$ is a correction to the *photon* propagator. It doesn’t have Dirac indices so $\gamma^\nu$ and $\sigma^{\nu\alpha}$ don’t apply.

Comment: Does Lorentz invariance authorize terms in $(p_\mu \gamma^\mu)^n$ with $n \geq 3$?

Comment: They don’t give anything new, since $\not p\not p=p^2I$.